# Run method on android app to download when folder is updated in Amazon S3?

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-sns

I have an android app and i am currently using alarm manager after every few hours to check if there is content update in my Amazon S3 bucket and then doing a download. I want to know if it is possible to send a notification to the device whenever a folder is updated on S3 and run a method which auto downloads the new content. 
I have looked at AWS SNS and its implementation but can't say weather it is the solution to my problem

Answer (score 0):

You could have [S3 send notifications to SNS](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/NotificationHowTo.html), and use [SNS mobile push notifications](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/SNSMobilePush.html) to notify your Android app that a file is available for download.

Alternatively, if you want to execute some logic on AWS to determine if a push notification should be sent, you could have S3 notify a Lambda function, which performs the logic and then creates an SNS message.